# Android Google+ issues

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to do the post on google-plus through my app. I am using this code for that but it not working it giving me message  that I couldn't post the message and I also having a doubt where i will use my clientId?.please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private Button shareButton=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        shareButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
        .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
        .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)  // recommended login scope for social features
        // .setScopes("profile")       // alternative basic login scope
        .build();
        // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not resolved.
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
        // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
        mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.share_button:
             Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
              .setType("text/plain")
              .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
              .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
              .getIntent();

          startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in console of google you have to check api access of google plus and also match your package with that package

Comment: have you done all process that ara saying in docs

Comment: yes I created my clientId but in that docs there is no details for using that id

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Comment: I used this documentation.

Comment: its your package name issue i 100 sure plz again generate project to google console give acject package name

Comment: ok.but can u pls tell me where we use clientid ?

Comment: there r no need to use client id its google directly manage from your package name

Comment: Product name:  googledemo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46668/discussion-between-anjali-tripathi-and-digvesh-patel)

Comment: have you got solution??

Comment: again you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a client ID anywhere in the app - its inferred from the app packagename and the SHA1 of the signing key (which is why it asks for those in the API console). However, you don't need sign in or a key at all to do the kind of basic sharing you're doing. To test, you might want to remove all PlusClient/sign in related code until you're comfortable the PlusShare builder is creating the intent properly.

Could you make sure you're using the latest version of Google Play services (4.1) and see if you have any issues still? If so, could you check whether any more error details appear in logcat.